# Trouble using flexboxes with css3

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey guys basically have to design a small website for my web-dev class! However Im having trouble getting my flexbox to work! It will Not align to the right so I have a column of information and I am very unsure as to why! screenshots Included! Thanks!

[The Html That I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7f3G.png)

[I want the orange row aligned against the right in a column!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0DF7.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: code code code ? ? ? (not pictures)

Answer (score 0):

Before you position the `aside` (or `float` it, or deploy it as a child element of a parent with `display: flex`), you'll need to give `.playercontainer` the following style rules:

```
.playercontainer {
display: block;
width: 240px; /* Any explicit width will do */
}
```